# CodeLite No executable specified, use 'target exec' error

Tags: c++, exec, executable, target, codelite

Today is my first day of using CodeLite (http://codelite.org/) and I keep getting random errors. I've managed to fix most of them, but didn't found how to fix this one:
No executable specified, use 'target exec'
It is shown when I press the Start or Continue debugger button. The only solution I found was this one: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/605071-codelite-cpp-variadic-templates-error/ but it didn't fix the problem. I want to use the program to run and make C++ codes, do I need to change something in the default settings? Thanks.

Here is the solution:

From the Main menu select Workspace and then New project. On the left side select Console > Simple executable (g++). On the right side fill the project name and path an click OK. You can now replace\edit the default main.cpp (will show on the left) contents with your code.

Comment: What type of project did you create? If you create lib project instead of executable it might give you this error.

Comment: It is executable project with VC++ compiler and GNU gdb debugger.

Comment: That's the problem. You cannot use VC++ compiler and GNU Debugger together. GDB doesn't understand VC++ code. Either use g++ compiler or Visual Studio. Unfortunately Codelite cannot use VC++ debugger.
EDIT: By VC++ code I mean assembly code, not C++ code.

Comment: Is the compile/link succeed ? Is the generated file exist ? Are the Project settings (Common Settings -> General : Program) correct ? Codelite version ? as a note, gdb is not compatible with VC++, I suggest to use g++ instead, or debugging inside visualStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are using VC++ compiler and tries to use GNU gdb debugger to debug that code.

That's not possible, because GDB cannot debug code compiled in VC++. Codelite cannot use VC++ debugger either. Your options are to use GNU g++ compiler or switch to Visual Studio. The Express edition is free and should suffice for all basic development requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing the `make` tool; I resolved installing the `build-essential` package with the command `sudo apt install build-essential`; I'm under +ubuntu.