# Codelite issue--No executable specified,use 'target exec

Tags: c++, debugging, codelite

I have just installed codelite in my windows 8.1.It shows error

```
  Debugger exited with the following error string:
   "No executable 
   specified,use 'target exec'"
```

I searched and found this [(another stackoverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309682/codelite-no-executable-specified-use-target-exec-error) I did the same as mentioned there but nothing really worked for me.I made a new project and selected Simple executable (g++) and GNU debugger as default debugger.Can anybody help me with this.Also it shows "Program exited with return code: 4199040".

Comment: You have build your project? There was no errors when building? It *is* an executable program you're building?

Comment: No sir,at the time of debugging my code.I tried both quick debug as well as default debugging process

Comment: I have build my project successfully,no error that time.Just tried simple Hello world program in c++.Also it shows "Program exited with return code: 4199040".

Comment: That return code is suspect, even without a return-statement in the `main` function, the compiler should automatically have added a `return 0;` at the end of the program, so the return code should have been zero. I don't know if that's related to your current problem, but it is a problem none the less.

Comment: Yes sir,i tried both with return 0; as well as without it but nothing happened.I think it has nothing to do with my problem

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you don't provide executable to run/debug:

Go to

```
Project settings... -> Common settings -> General
```

and fill correct information for

```
Executable to Run / Debug
```

Answer (score 1):

Jarod42 provided a 'close enough' answer. On Linux the steps seem to be:

```
Workspace -> Open Active Project Settings... -> General
```

and fill correct information for

```
Executable to Run / Debug
```

Answer (score 0):

In the command prompt:

1. gdb (program type: example python or c or c++ etc)
   If am running python program then the command will be **gdb python**
2. then (gdb) **run program_name.py**